# Is there a way of checking for multiple string sequences with String.matches in Java?

Tags: java, string, multiple-matches

I want to look for any of the following sequences: either one of `*` `-` `/` `+` followed by a `*` `+` `/`

for example:
`4+*2` is something I am looking for.
`4+5/2` is not

```
if (combinedArray.matches("[-*+/][*+/]"))
{
...code
}
```

I'd be happy to know what I did wrong.

I basicly want it to have the same logic as this:

```
if (combinedArray.contains("*/") | combinedArray.contains("*+") | combinedArray.contains("**") 
        | combinedArray.contains("//") | combinedArray.contains("/+") | combinedArray.contains("/*") 
        | combinedArray.contains("+/") | combinedArray.contains("++") | combinedArray.contains("+*") 
        | combinedArray.contains("-/") | combinedArray.contains("-+") | combinedArray.contains("-*") )
~~~
```

Comment: You may be forgetting about what could come between the two things you are searching for. You should include some example inputs, and what matches you are hoping to find in them.

Comment: Your samples don't **match** (which would imply the whole input matches the regex). You might want to use `find` instead.